# Mapping JPA entities to inheritance hierarchy

Tags: inheritance, jpa, mapping, hierarchy

Lets say I have an object model similar to the following:

```
abstract class Vehicle {
   String guid;
   String name;
   Double price;
}
class SUV extends Vehicle {
   Integer towingCapacity;
}
class Hybrid extends Vehicle {
   Integer batterySize;
}
```

I need to use JPA and map this hierarchy into the database. I've chosen to go with the 'Joined Table Per Class' approach, as outlined here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping

So essentially I have a `Vehicle` parent table, with an `SUV` and `Hybrid` table having a foreign key to `Vehicle`. The reason I chose this solution is that I like the normalized schema, and in addition `Vehicle.guid` needs to be globally unique, so having a parent table with that field - as opposed to scattered throughout individual tables - simplifies this UNIQUE constraint.

I'm still relatively new to JPA and I have no idea how to set these up as JPA entities. Would class `Vehicle` be a MappedSuperclass? Also, I know I will need to add an @Id to each entity, but would `SUV` and `Hybrid` use the foreign key to the `Vehicle` table or would I have to use the primary key from the child tables as the identifier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is defined once for the whole hierarchy and is inherited, so the `@Id` attribute in the `Vehicle` class is enough.

`@MappedSuperclass` means that the class is not mapped to a separate table, but rather is part of it's children's tables. If you want a normalized schema, make `Vehicle` an entity as well.

You do not need to define foreign keys for child entities. This is done by the persistence provider and can be transparent to the developer.

Please note that `JOINED` inheritance strategy is less performant than the default `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy. `SINGLE_TABLE`  requires more space and does not really  support non-nullable columns for derived entities.

Comment: So based on your suggestion I have `Vehicle`, `SUV`, and `Hybrid` all Entities. `Vehicle` has the @Id, and `SUV`, `Hybrid` have no @Id, just the necessary @Column. When I try to persist SUV with that setup I get an error stating that table Vehicle is not found, and directly below there is an attempt to prepare a statement to table Vehicle containing every column from both Vehicle and SUV tables. It doesn't seem like the PU realizes the hierarchy. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I was missing `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="VehicleId", referencedColumnName="VehicleId")` on the `SUV` entity and `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` on `Vehicle` entity. This has resolved the prepared stmt issue above, but still get table not found.

Comment: Strange, if I change the table generation strategy in my persistence unit to create, then everything works fine. I can't find where the tables are created though. Must be an issue with the persistence unit that I'm not seeing. But at least the persistence is working :) thanks.